# CoffeeScript syntax using multiple variables inside for-loop

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, syntax, coffeescript

What's the equivalent CoffeeScript syntax of the native JS' multiple variables for-loop?

```
for(var a = 0, b = 0; a < 100; a++, b += 10)
{
  console.log(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `for` construct like JavaScript's, CoffeeScript relies on *comprehensions* and *ranges*. From [the documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> The only low-level loop that CoffeeScript provides is the `while` loop.

You could do something involving a range for `a`, with `b` being updated manually:

```
b = 0
for a in [0..99]
  console.log a b
  b += 10
```

Or use that `while`:

```
a = 0
b = 0
while a < 100
  console.log a b
  ++a
  b += 10
```